# Angular clear cached router url value

Tags: angular, url, redirect, angular-router

There is a situation where user login into the app and URL being change from `localhost/login` to the `localhost/`. After that user goes on the page B (URL is being changed to `the localhost/B`) and makes logout from the app.

The user makes login again and app automatically redirects to the page B.

I'm trying to get right route using router events:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
         console.log(event.url);
      }
    })
  }
```

and the result is always URL from the last visited page (B).

There is no login page, but you can try to refresh
[Stackblitz](https://angular-router-event-5ccmzg.stackblitz.io/B)

Is it possible to clear router url (within logout action) in order to prevents from redirects to the last visited page (page B)?

Comment: are not you redirecting after login and logout? where is the code for Login/Logout

Comment: @Furquan yes, the redirect works, but the source of the problem is in the event because it always returns value from the router.url